# jQuery: Why is this function firing 4 times?

Tags: jquery, function, animation, triggers, scroll

I've written a bunch of jQuery stuff to help my friend out with his online portfolio which can be found here: http://bradleyrogerson.com/ (for reference of what I am about to describe).

Here is also a direct link to the javascript: http://bradleyrogerson.com/static/js/actions-take2.js

It is a rather long file, so it's probably best if I do not put it all in a code block on Stack Overflow directly.

The problem itself is pretty simple, and you can easily see broken animation on the site (link above).
Essentially my `hideProject()` function which basically hides the project and then slides the original overview of all his projects back into view is firing 4 times for a reason I simply cannot find.

The key issue with this is that in the last callback of the animations taking place, I animate the `scrollLeft` property of the `body` & `html` element so that is visually slides back to where you had left off before going to the 'more info` view.

Because the animation is firing 4 times, there is about a 1.2 second window in which time the viewport is animated which effectively breaks the ability to scroll right during that time.

This can easily be reproduced by going to [his site](http://bradleyrogerson.com/) right now and clicking on the image furthest to the right (horizontal scroll page layout), then once you've viewed the project simply click one of the images to trigger the `hideProject()` function and once the viewport has animated as far as it can go try immediately scrolling to the left.

You'll notice that you won't be able to with the animation still firing pushing your attempts to go left out the window forcing the `scrollLeft` value upon you again and again (4 times).

I have commented the [javascript file](http://bradleyrogerson.com/static/js/actions-take2.js) very well (at least I think so) so it should be pretty easy to read and understand once opened.

I would really appreciate an answer to the issue, how to fix it but most importantly some advice on why it broke in the first place so I can learn from this and not make this mistake again.

Many thanks for reading.

Jannis

**Note:** the function in question (at least I think this is the cause) is on `line 212` in [this file](http://bradleyrogerson.com/static/js/actions-take2.js).

Comment: why do you apply the animation to both 'body' and 'html' tags? this may explain at least 2 times firing the callback

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The reason is that I have set my page overflow settings on the `html` element, but animating just the `html` element didn't trigger the animation in webkit browsers, adding `body` into the mix fixed that. Perhaps however I need to apply all overflow settings to the `body` instead and only animate that element instead?

Comment: @Jannis How did you fix this? I am having this same strange issue where my animation callback is firing exactly four times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding breakpoints, I can only see this function firing twice, once because you bound it to a click event for the element #project-media, the other because you bound it to the hashchange() event. Just make the click event trigger a hashchange() instead of calling hideProject() or simply remove the binding altogether. The binding is made on line 331.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely was a mistake but removing this and checking that it now only fires once per click (the click only changes the hash value) still fires the animation 4 times. Probably because of animating both `html` & `body` at the same time as mentioned by shellmax. Will have to remove that and make sure it works after all that.